# kotlin proguard rules for kotlin reflection

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, proguard, rules

Hello everyone I have an issue with kotlin reflection in release mode. I set proguard rules for keeping the data classes, enums, and reflection package but in a release mode , functions that are using kotlin reflection face exception, and the application will crash.
The exception from logcat is

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.error.ErrorModuleDescriptor.<clinit>(ErrorModuleDescriptor.java:23)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.error.ErrorUtils.<clinit>(ErrorUtils.java:14)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.error.ErrorUtils.createErrorType(ErrorUtils.java)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeUtils.<clinit>(TypeUtils.java:36)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeUtils.makeUnsubstitutedType(TypeUtils.java:213)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.AbstractClassDescriptor$1.invoke(AbstractClassDescriptor.java:49)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.AbstractClassDescriptor$1.invoke(AbstractClassDescriptor.java:46)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.AbstractClassDescriptor.getDefaultType(AbstractClassDescriptor.java:175)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.createMockJavaIoSerializableType(JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.java:91)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.<init>(JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.java:59)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltIns$customizer$2.invoke(JvmBuiltIns$customizer.java:76)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltIns$customizer$2.invoke(JvmBuiltIns$customizer.java:75)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.StorageKt.getValue(StorageKt.java:42)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltIns.getCustomizer(JvmBuiltIns.java:75)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.DeserializationComponentsForJava.<init>(DeserializationComponentsForJava.java:80)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.DeserializationComponentsForJavaKt.makeDeserializationComponentsForJava(DeserializationComponentsForJavaKt.java:192)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.DeserializationComponentsForJava$Companion.createModuleData(DeserializationComponentsForJava.java:123)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.runtime.components.RuntimeModuleData$Companion.create(RuntimeModuleData.java:32)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ModuleByClassLoaderKt.getOrCreateModule(ModuleByClassLoaderKt.java:58)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.invoke(KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData.java:36)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.invoke(KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData.java:35)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data.getModuleData(KDeclarationContainerImpl.java:35)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke(KClassImpl$Data$descriptor.java:50)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke(KClassImpl$Data$descriptor.java:48)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.java:48)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.java:182)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getMemberScope$kotlin_reflection(KClassImpl.java:191)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers.java:162)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers.java:162)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDeclaredNonStaticMembers(KClassImpl.java:162)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl$Data$allNonStaticMembers.java:171)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl$Data$allNonStaticMembers.java:171)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getAllNonStaticMembers(KClassImpl.java:171)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl$Data$allMembers.java:177)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$allMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl$Data$allMembers.java:177)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getAllMembers(KClassImpl.java:177)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getMembers(KClassImpl.java:195)
 at com.ebcom.ewano.util.AppUtils.readClassProperty(AppUtils.java:1001)
kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(BaseContinuationImpl.java:33)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:106)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException
Caused by: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readRawBytesSlowPath(CodedInputStream.java:1187)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readBytes(CodedInputStream.java:517)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:238)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipMessage(CodedInputStream.java:287)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:245)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipMessage(CodedInputStream.java:287)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:245)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessageLite.java:73)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$StringTable.<init>(ProtoBuf.java:342)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$StringTable.<init>(ProtoBuf.java:301)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$StringTable$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtoBuf$StringTable.java:384)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$StringTable$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtoBuf$StringTable.java:379)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:495)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$PackageFragment.<init>(ProtoBuf.java:24538)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$PackageFragment.<init>(ProtoBuf.java:24485)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$PackageFragment$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtoBuf$PackageFragment.java:24607)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$PackageFragment$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtoBuf$PackageFragment.java:24602)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:192)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:209)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.ProtoBuf$PackageFragment.parseFrom(ProtoBuf.java:24821)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.builtins.ReadPackageFragmentKt.readBuiltinsPackageFragment(ReadPackageFragmentKt.java:16)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsPackageFragmentImpl$Companion.create(BuiltInsPackageFragmentImpl.java:37)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl.createBuiltInPackageFragmentProvider(BuiltInsLoaderImpl.java:60)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl.createPackageFragmentProvider(BuiltInsLoaderImpl.java:35)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.createBuiltInsModule(KotlinBuiltIns.java:105)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.DefaultBuiltIns.<init>(DefaultBuiltIns.java:24)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.DefaultBuiltIns.<init>(DefaultBuiltIns.java:21)
 at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.DefaultBuiltIns.<clinit>(DefaultBuiltIns.java:31)
 ... 75 more
```

can anyone help ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `@keep` annotation like this

```
@Keep
public void foo() {
    ...
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep

Comment: On functions which using reflection you mean ?